# Get data from async storage react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to get data from *async* storage and add it to an array. I use `console.log()` function to check data and it works correctly, but when I tried to push data to the array it did not work and the function returns an empty array.

```
getData(){
    result = []
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((object, key)=>(
            console.log(object[1]),
             result.push(object[1])
          ));
        });
      });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Because it is a promise. You should `await`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use async await to achieve this...

```
getData = async () => {
    result = []
    await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((object, key)=>(
                console.log(object[1]);
                result.push(object[1]);
                ));
            });
        });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its dont resolve my problem, ```console.log()``` work correctly, but i anyway get empty array

Comment: you have made a comma after console.log() i think you should do a semicolon there and also you need to await your retun object

Answer (score 0):

you need to properly use async/await because AsyncStorage relies heavily on promises.

```
getData = async () => {
    result = []
    await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys(async (err, keys) => {
        await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((object, key)=>(
                console.log(object[1]);
                result.push(object[1]);
            ));
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```